# How to have protected set functions?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, set

I'm working in ActionScript 3, but I'm guessing this is a universal concept.

I've recently stumbled upon the world of get and set functions, and I immediately tried to apply it to my code, since before I'd need to run an explicit set function so that two parameters would keep up to date with each other.

However, I only ever actually SET the variable in a subclass to where the variable is defined - so I'd like it to be protected. Unfortunately, the code seems to only work when the set function is public, and I have no clue. All the examples I could find online never used a set function except outside of the class it was defined in.

This isn't so much something that's going to be difficult to work around (I would just use an explicit set function) as something I want to understand to become a better programmer, and maybe help someone else who is in my position.

Here's my code which might make my point a bit clearer:

```
    private var _iColumn:int;
    private var _iRow:int;
    public function get iColumn():int { return _iColumn; }
    public function get iRow():int { return _iRow; }

    protected function set iColumn(setValue:int):void {
        _iColumn = setValue;
        resetClickArea();
    }
    protected function set iRow(setValue:int):void {
        _iRow = setValue;
        resetClickArea();
    }

    public function TileElement(column:int, row:int) 
    {
        iColumn = column;   // Complains that property is read-only
        iRow = row;         // Complains that property is read-only
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't sound very language-agnostic, it sounds like a problem you're specifically having with Actionscript!

Comment: I'll change the tag then, I was only guessing that it could be applied to other languages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both getter and setter need to have the same namespace (public, protected or private) so if the getter needs to be public your only option is to make the setter public as well or replace the setter by a protected function like setIRow or something.

Making both getter and setter protected would make valid code but of course you won't be able to access the the property from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages don't even have this nice feature of `get` and `set` keywords. You would be better off creating your own getter and setter functions `getRow();` and `setRow(r);`. One other bonus is that you don't get too attached to this `AS3` feature, and it would be easier to work within other languages like `C++`.

Comment: Ah, ok! I thought I saw it somewhere else, but it must have been an isolated case.

Comment: Important also is that setter/getter are slightly faster than pure function calls.

Comment: @BotMaster I didn't know that.  Do you know of an article discussing the topic?

Comment: @Iggy  I don't agree that it would be easier to work within other languages like C++.  It isn't always easier to work in another language.  Especially, if the program is going to be run on a device.  C++ would offer very little help in this case.  AS3 and Flex Framework are still very viable options for producing applications for multiple platforms.

Comment: What I meant by that was that there are no `get` and `set` keywords in languages like C++. So if you ever go into other languages you might have a hard time accepting the reality. ;) For me especially I jump from one language to the other constantly and I really like having a similar programming style everywhere I code.